# Youtube videos run very slowly

Tags: video, youtube

I am primarily a Windows user. I'm dual-booting Ubuntu 13.04 using Wubi and I've noticed that Youtube is much slower on Ubuntu than it is on Windows in the same network... Like a LOT slower. I find that Windows typically loads 720p faster than Ubuntu does 240p, and sometimes even 144p isn't fast enough. I know this shouldn't be a problem, but unfortunately - being fairly new to Linux - I lack the technical expertise to solve this issue. I've already tried HTML5 with no observable results, but the problem persists independent of what browser I'm using. If anyone has a solution, I would much appreciate a noob-friendly explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

- Try with Google Chrome
- Install the proprietary video drivers by doing the following:

  1. Open the Ubuntu Software Center (Centre if you're not American)
  2. Navigate to the universal menu towards the top of the screen and select `Edit`->`Software Sources`.
  3. Wait for the window to come up.
  4. Select the tab `Additional Drivers`.
  5. Select a proprietary driver if it's available and install it.
- Edit the file `/etc/adobe/mms.cfg` (creating the file if it exists) and add/edit `OverrideGPUValidation=true`. Save the file and restart the computer. This is a protected system directory, so you can edit it by running `sudo nano /etc/adobe/mms.cfg` in a terminal (`Ctrl-Alt-T` opens a terminal) and running `Ctrl-X` and `Y` to save once you've finished.

Let us know how that works.

Comment: Apparently I don't have any proprietary drivers. I did try writing to mms.cfg and restarting like you said, but there still seems to be no improvement...

Comment: Did you try Chrome?

Comment: I did try Chrome. Turns out the problem wasn't with my computer. I reset my router and everything works fine now... don't know why I didn't think of that first. Sorry about wasting your time.